# App icon in Android Studio has green stroke?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, icons

I'm new to Android Studio and encountered an issue while trying to change the app icon in my Android project. Despite following several tutorial videos step by step, the resulting app icon has a green stroke around it. I have tried using different images and adjusting their size, but the issue persists.

To troubleshoot further, I created a new project and noticed that even the default Android icon has a green background when the app is first created and run.

How can I remove the green stroke from the app icon in Android Studio? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

[App Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4hop.png)
[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSyNq.png)

Replacing the default app icon with a custom one:

I replaced the default app icon in the res/mipmap or res/drawable directory with a custom icon that does not have a green stroke.
I expected the new custom app icon to be displayed without any green stroke.
Adjusting the size of the custom app icon:

I tried resizing the custom app icon to match the recommended sizes for different densities (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc.).
I expected that resizing the icon would remove the green stroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an automatic suggestion that the launcher provides to commonly launched app when no app icon has been dragged into that spot. This is a specific feature for the default emulator (and Pixel) launcher and not something that you'll see on other launchers.

If you manually drag your app icon to that spot, you'll find that the stroke that indicates that this is an automatic suggestion will be removed.

There's nothing you need to do at the Android Studio level you need to do.

Comment: You are legendary! Thanks for the help! This was the solution!